# Is Christ real name Yeshu'ah H3444

Tags: jesus, christology, soteriology, god

I have been studying the text within Genesis for years and have found that when approached in literal terms that Jacob received the name of the Angel of the LORD as his blessing in Genesis 32.  If you look at

Gen 32:29 KJV "And Jacob asked him, and said, Tell me, I pray thee, thy name. And he said, Wherefore is it that thou dost ask after my name? And he blessed him there."

Jacob did not ask for a new name, he asked for the name of the angel!!! So if he knew this angel was God why did he do this?  Because He knew this Angel was not the Father Jehovah?
Later we see Jacob use the Name Salvation (Yeshu'ah H3444) when transition between Dan and Gad, to denote the name he Waits on.  Is it possible Jacob actually received the name and tells us in Genesis 49:18?  Otherwise what is the significance of the word Salvation in the Bible if it was not first a name?  Especially considering this same exact word is used for his name in Matthew 1:21, as we know no other man actually pardoned anyone from sin, only the Angel, who is God, the Messenger and the Word of God.  We also can reference Judges 2 to further see the entire nation of Israel knew the Angel of the LORD was The God of Israel.

Comment: Welcome to the forum! Here's something that you might enjoy--an expert explains how Jesus would have pronounced his own name:
https://youtu.be/na22KkydPRs

Answer (score 0):

**First:** The name that Jacob received was [Israel](https://www.christianity.com/wiki/bible/what-is-the-meaning-of-israel-in-the-bible.html) which means "God contends" or "one who struggles with God".

**Second:** There is a difference between "Yeshu'ah" (יְשׁוּעָה) and "Yeshua" (יֵשׁוּעַ) which lies in their grammatical forms and usage within the Hebrew language:

**[Yeshuah (יְשׁוּעָה):](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h3444/kjv/wlc/0-1/) (Also [see](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/3442.htm))**

- "Yeshuah" is a Hebrew noun that means "salvation" or "deliverance."
- It is derived from the root word "[yasa](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h3467/kjv/wlc/0-1/)" (יָשַׁע), which means "to
  save" or "to deliver."
- This form is used in various contexts throughout the Hebrew Bible to
  refer to salvation or deliverance from physical or spiritual
  oppression.

**[Yeshua (יֵשׁוּעַ):](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h3442/kjv/wlc/0-1/) (Also [see](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/3442.htm))**

- "Yeshua" is a Hebrew personal name.
- It is also derived from the root word "[yasa](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h3467/kjv/wlc/0-1/)" (יָשַׁע), meaning "to
  save" or "to deliver."
- This form is specifically used as a personal name, particularly in
  reference to Jesus of Nazareth in the New Testament.
- In English translations, it is commonly rendered as "Jesus."
- The name "Yeshua" reflects the person and mission of Jesus Christ as
  the Savior of humanity, fulfilling God's promise of salvation.

**What is the significance of the word Salvation in the Bible if it was not first a name?**

> I have waited for your salvation, O Lord!

The statement displays Jacob's confidence in the deliverance and salvation that comes from God. The term "your salvation" is used to show the deliverance or salvation that only comes from God. Jacob recognizes God's supreme authority and shows his dependence on salvation for both himself and his descendants.

Now, throughout his life, Jacob encountered numerous challenges and trials, during which he witnessed God's support. By blessing Gad, Jacob demonstrated his belief that God will continue as their source of deliverance and salvation. That being said, 'waiting' implies a period of trust and hope in God's promises.

Comment: I meant that he received the name he asked for...  have you read that Jacob asked God for his name.  Isn't it interesting that the angel who is God has a different name than LORD???

Comment: Furthermore, Salvation is the exact word given by Gabriel, he shall save from sin.  The Angel of the LORD was the only one sent to judge sins remember Exodus 32:34 please.  He was specifically called out to be christ by LORD when speaking to Moses after forgiving Israel of the golden calf....